# android layout view fixed width, siblings auto fit parent remain width with weighting

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

my currently xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mlistview_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:textSize="19sp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to achieve something like:

```
// parent width matches device width
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ this  +                                          +              +
+ block + this fit parent remain width             + this block   +
+ fixed + this block weighted 70%                  + weighted 30% +
+ 30dp  +                                          +              +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

one view has fixed width, then other view should use weighting to fill remain width

any ideas? googled but seems no similar question

Comment: wats the problem with your code ??

Comment: other views is move outside the LinearLayout

Comment: Add orientation as horizontal to your linearlayout and wat u mean by other views, coz this code would give wat u have described

Comment: fixed it, seems is extra java code affected the layout, still looking for the problem source